# Convert this SQL query into Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have a c# webforms application that uses Linq2SQL, SQL Server, .net 4.5

I know SQL reasonably well, but am finding Linq *very* hard work.

SQL although tricky usually makes sense, but I find linq almost impossible to write unless I can find a identical example online. This time I cannot find one.

I am using a view within the SQL to simplify the process and cut out the need for insane linq syntax joining tables together, however as views won't allow `ORDER BY` statements I am a bit stuck. I can get the query to work perfectly in a stored procedure, but I gave up trying to get the data back through linq after 5-hours scouring of the 'Net to find out how.

The original `ORDER BY` sorts the `Name` column but ignores a "The " at the start of the field giving:

```
Apple
The Banana
Orange
Pear
```

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 Name, Year, Data1, Data2
FROM v_List_Items
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 4)) = 'the ' 
           THEN SUBSTRING(Name, 5, len(Name)) 
           ELSE NAME 
    END ASC
```

Any ideas ?

Also being able to change the 100 results filter dynamically would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try writing the same logic in the `OrderBy` lambda?

Comment: @krystanhonour No, the question is how to sort by excluding the `The ` prefix.

Comment: Seems so however the original question was poorly worded, I have edited to make clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the following sql insert code into a table

```
INSERT INTO NamedFruit(Name) Values('Apple')
GO
INSERT INTO NamedFruit(Name) Values('The Banana')
GO
INSERT INTO NamedFruit(Name) Values('Orange')
GO
INSERT INTO NamedFruit(Name) Values('Pear')
```

used the following query

```
NamedFruits.OrderBy(s=>s.Name.StartsWith("The ") ? s.Name.Substring(4) : s.Name);
```

results:

```
Apple 
The Banana 
Orange 
Pear
```

Should be no issue.

Generated sql was:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'The %'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 4
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Name]
FROM [NamedFruit] AS [t0]
ORDER BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t0].[Name] LIKE @p0 THEN CONVERT(NVarChar,SUBSTRING([t0].[Name], @p1 + 1, CONVERT(Int,DATALENGTH([t0].[Name]))))
        ELSE CONVERT(NVarChar,CONVERT(NVarChar(20),[t0].[Name]))
     END)
```

Comment: I hate downvotes with no comment on a nicely written answer that actually does what the op asked for. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work with Ling to SQL, but it should give you a start. I'm using a ternary operator to determine the string to use for the sort.

```
var fruits = new List<string> 
{
    "Apple",
    "The Banana",
    "Orange",
    "Pear"
};

var orderedFruits = fruits
    .OrderBy(s => 
        s.StartsWith("The ") 
            ? s.Substring(4) 
            : s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute the SQL within LINQ, there's no need to translate. For example:

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");
IEnumerable<Customer> results = db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>
(@"SELECT c1.custid as CustomerID, c2.custName as ContactName
    FROM customer1 as c1, customer2 as c2
    WHERE c1.custid = c2.custid"
);
```

Source: [How to: Directly Execute SQL Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This is better because you have no guarantees that a particular piece of LINQ generates a particular SQL query.

Comment: Boy, no. This isn't LINQ at all. And it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It's LINQ2SQL. See the attached reference if you disagree... You can chain any other LINQ operator to it, etc. In what way is it *not* LINQ?

Comment: ORMs usually do provide a way to execute raw SQL, but even though the ORM may be LINQ-based, *the statement itself* isn't LINQ. And that's what the question is about.